# Trying to concatenate js files with webpack (like a gulp script)

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

I want to reproduce this Gulp script with webpack to have only one process who listen on files but i can't make it work. This is my Gulp task

```
gulp.task('scripts', function(){

return gulp.src( WATCH_SCRIPTS.SCRIPTS )
  .pipe(plumber())
  .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
  .pipe(concat('plugins.min.js'))
  .pipe(babel({ compact: false, babelrc: false, presets: ['es2015-allow-top-level-this'] }))
  .pipe(ifElse(PROD_ENV,
    () => {return uglify({
      hoist_vars: true,
      global_defs: {
        jQuery: false,
        $: false,
      }
    })},
    () => {return sourcemaps.write('./')}
  ))
  .pipe(plumber.stop())
  .pipe(gulp.dest(BUILD_PATH + '/js'));
});
```

I tried with the expose-loader, but it always misses some dependancies.

```
{
  name: 'scripts',
  target: 'web',
  entry: glob.sync('./src/assets/js/**/*.js'),
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/js/'),
    filename: 'plugins.min.js',
    sourceMapFilename: 'plugins.min.js.map',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /[\/]global\.js$/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'expose-loader',
          options: 'Materialize'
        }]
      },
      {
        test: /[\/]jquery\.js$/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'expose-loader',
          options: 'jQuery'
        },{
          loader: 'expose-loader',
          options: '$'
        }]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I tried with the babel-loader with the preset (like in the gulp task)

```
presets: ['es2015-allow-top-level-this']
```

Materialize was undefined from this file https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/blob/master/js/global.js.

Can i just listen to files changes and start my `gulp scripts` or is there a way to concatenate files directly? I'm very new to webpack 2.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try ['script-loader'](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/script-loader) It does not concatenate, but it executes the script in the global context, which is what I originally needed when looking for "simple concatenation".