# Unable to concatenate multiple JS files using Webpack

Tags: webpack-2

I am using Webpack 2 in my project to transpile and bundle ReactJS files along with a few other tasks. Here's what my config looks like:

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
var config = {
    module: {
      loaders: [
        {
          exclude: /(node_modules)/,
          loader: "babel-loader",
          query: {
            presets: ["es2015", "react"]
          }
        },
        {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
            fallback: "style-loader",
            use: ["css-loader", "sass-loader"]
          })
        }
      ]
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ mangle: false, sourcemap: false }),
      new ExtractTextPlugin({
        filename: "../../public/dist/main.css"
      })
    ],
};
var indexConfig = Object.assign({}, config, {
    name: "index",
    entry: "./public/javascripts/build/index.js",
    output: {
       path: __dirname + "/public/dist",
       filename: "index.min.js",
    },
});
var aboutConfig = Object.assign({}, config, {
    name: "about",
    entry: "./public/javascripts/build/about.js",
    output: {
       path: __dirname + "/public/dist",
       filename: "about.min.js"
    },
});

// Return Array of Configurations
module.exports = [
    indexConfig, aboutConfig
];
```

As evident, I am using multiple build configurations for JS, one for each page. Now, I need to add some Bootstrap JS to the mix for which I also need JQuery and Tether. Thus, I have the following 3 files in my library folder:

1. jquery-3.2.1.min.js
2. tether.min.js
3. bootstrap.min.js

I need these 3 files to be concatenated and bundled along with the main JS files being emitted by Webpack (e.g., index.min.js, etc.). To do so, I modified my `entry` item thus:

```
entry: {
  a: "./public/javascripts/lib/jquery-3.2.1.min.js",
  b: "./public/javascripts/lib/tether.min.js",
  b: "./public/javascripts/lib/bootstrap.min.js",
  c: "./public/javascripts/build/index.js"
}
```

However, doing so throws the following error:

```
ERROR in chunk a [entry]
    index.min.js
    Conflict: Multiple assets emit to the same filename index.min.js

    ERROR in chunk b [entry]
    index.min.js
    Conflict: Multiple assets emit to the same filename index.min.js

    ERROR in chunk c [entry]
    index.min.js
    Conflict: Multiple assets emit to the same filename index.min.js
```

Obviously this is because Webpack is expecting multiple output files for multiple entry items. Is there any way to overcome this problem? An [existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43879823/trying-to-concatenate-js-files-with-webpack-like-a-gulp-script) illustrating a similar problem doesn't seem to have any acceptable answer at the moment.

**UPDATE**:

Tried using the Commons chunk plugin as suggested by terales, but Webpack threw the following error this time:

```
ERROR in multi jquery tether bootstrap
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jquery' in '/home/ubuntu/panda'
     @ multi jquery tether bootstrap

    ERROR in multi jquery tether bootstrap
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tether' in '/home/ubuntu/panda'
     @ multi jquery tether bootstrap

    ERROR in multi jquery tether bootstrap
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'bootstrap' in '/home/ubuntu/panda'
     @ multi jquery tether bootstrap

    ERROR in chunk vendor [entry]
    index.min.js
    Conflict: Multiple assets emit to the same filename index.min.js
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your libs shouldn't be entries. They called "vendors" in Webpack's terms.

### See [minimum working example repo](https://github.com/terales/extracting-vendor-chunks-with-webpack-2).

In your code you should implicitly [extract common vendor chunk](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting-libraries/#implicit-common-vendor-chunk):

```
var config = {
    entry: {                       // <-- you could make two entries
        index: './index.js',       //     in a more Webpack's way,
        about: './about.js'        //     instead of providing array of confings
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].min.js',
        path: __dirname + '/dist'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            // Fix error 'JQuery is not defined' if any
            { test: require.resolve("jquery"), loader: "expose-loader?$!expose-loader?jQuery" },
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        // this assumes your vendor imports exist in the node_modules directory
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'vendor',
            minChunks: function (module) {
                return module.context && module.context.indexOf('node_modules') !== -1;
            }
        })
    ]
};
```

Comment: Did you install jquery and other libs with npm?

Comment: Yes, I did. Both JQuery and Tether.

Comment: There could be a lot of places where config or files may fail. I'll prepare minimum working example for you

Comment: updated answer, see linked repo for a fully working example